# Fast, python-ish way of ranking chunks of 1's in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a numpy array consisting of `0`'s and `1`'s. Each sequence of `1`'s within the array stands for occurrence of one event. I want to label elements corresponding to an event with event-specific ID number (and the rest of array elements with `np.nan`) I surely can do that in a loop, but is there more "python-ish" (fast, vectorized) way of doing it?

Example of numpy array with 3 events I want to label.

```
import numpy as np 
arr = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
some_func(arr)

# Expected output of some_func I search for: 
# [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,0,0,0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,2,2,2]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to label and luckily, there's one with SciPy, [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) -

```
In [43]: from scipy.ndimage import label

In [47]: out = label(arr)[0]

In [48]: np.where(arr==0,np.nan,out-1)
Out[48]: 
array([nan, nan, nan,  0.,  0.,  0., nan, nan, nan,  1.,  1., nan, nan,
       nan,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
```

Another with some NumPy *work* -

```
def rank_chunks(arr):
    m = np.r_[False,arr.astype(bool)]
    idx = np.flatnonzero(m[:-1] < m[1:])
    id_ar = np.zeros(len(arr),dtype=float)
    id_ar[idx[1:]] = 1
    out = id_ar.cumsum()
    out[arr==0] = np.nan
    return out
```

Another with `masking` + `np.repeat` -

```
def rank_chunks_v2(arr):
    m = np.r_[False,arr.astype(bool),False]
    idx = np.flatnonzero(m[:-1] != m[1:])
    l = idx[1::2]-idx[::2]
    out = np.full(len(arr),np.nan,dtype=float)
    out[arr!=0] = np.repeat(np.arange(len(l)),l)
    return out
```

Timings (tiling given input to 1Mx) -

```
In [153]: arr_big = np.tile(arr,1000000)

In [154]: %timeit np.where(arr_big==0,np.nan,label(arr_big)[0]-1)
     ...: %timeit rank_chunks(arr_big)
     ...: %timeit rank_chunks_v2(arr_big)
1 loop, best of 3: 312 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 263 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 229 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

A really cool way to do this is using the [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) clustering algorithm. It might not be the most efficient for this specific task, BUT it is resilient in case you want to give a minimum number of 1's per event, or allow a gap of a certain number of zeroes within an event.

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import numpy as np

max_gap = 1
min_samples = 1

# Get indices of every element that belongs to a certain event
input_values = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])  
positives_indices = np.where(input_values > 0)[0]

# Turn the indices into a 2D array of so called 'examples'
X = positives_indices.reshape(-1, 1)

# Train a model and transform the data in one
clustering = DBSCAN(eps=max_gap, min_samples=min_samples) \
    .fit_predict(X)

# Get results, yields (index, event_id)
zip(X, clustering)
```